# Data extraction with multiple conditional filtering & probability using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
**Clip                     mode codec   duration**
\\good\multimedia\clip_a    vbr mpeg    10sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_b    cbr aac     5sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_c    vbr aac     30sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_d    vbr pcm     120sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_e    vbr pcm     200se
\\good\multimedia\clip_f    cbr pcm     15sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_g    vbr mpeg    18sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_h    cbr aac     40sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_i    cbr mpeg    56sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_j    cbr mpeg    130sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_k    amr pcm     10sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_l    amr pcm     6sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_m    vbr pcm     76sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_n    vbr pcm     80sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_o    cbr mpeg    96sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_p    cbr mpeg    27sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_q    amr aac     33sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_r    amr aac     21sec
\\good\multimedia\clip_s    amr mpeg    12sec
```

Hi experts, I am in process of data extraction from large spreadsheet (please see above sample sheet with small data). Below are my conditions based on which I need to extract data from this spreadsheet:

Select all possible combinations of clips with below conditions and output to new spreadsheet:

**Data Selection conditions:**
 1. codec: Select 40% aac, 30%mpeg, 20% pcm
 2. Bitratemode: Select 30% vbr, 30% cbr and 40% amr
 3. Duration: Total run time for selected clips should be 1 hour with short clips (1-10s): 25%, Medium clips (10-120s): 70% & long clips (120+): 5%

I am looking into Pandas but completely new with that so I am not sure if this type of filtering is possible in Pandas where we have to cross join multiple conditions for filtering along with selecting data with probability in each column.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459694/data-selection-based-on-probability and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605649/multiple-conditional-filtering-with-probability-using-pandas

Comment: @ayhan : thanks there are no solutions in those questions so really doesn't help to understand and learn how to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have `3x3x3=27` combinations of values in your sample space. You need to calculate how many rows `X` you'd need from each to achieve your desired proportions, and use `.sample(n=X)` on the subset. See below a random breakdown of the 27 subsets:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

ids = [''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)]) for i in range(10)]
df['ID'] = np.random.choice(ids, size=10000)
df['codec'] = np.random.choice(['aac', 'mpeg', 'pcm'], size=10000)
df['mode'] = np.random.choice(['vbr', 'cbr', 'amr'], size=10000)
df['duration'] = np.random.randint(1, 200, 10000)
df['duration'] = pd.cut(df.duration, bins=[0, 10, 120, df.duration.max()], labels=['short', 'medium', 'long'])

codecs = df.codec.drop_duplicates().tolist()
modes = df.loc[:, 'mode'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
durations = df.duration.drop_duplicates().tolist()

permutations = list(product(codecs, modes, durations))
sample = {}

for permutation in permutations:
    sample[permutation] = len(df[(df.codec == permutation[0]) & (df.loc[:, 'mode'] == permutation[1]) & (df.duration == permutation[2])])

sample = pd.Series(sample)
sample.div(len(sample))

aac   amr  long      15.111111
           medium    22.259259
           short      2.111111
      cbr  long      16.592593
           medium    22.555556
           short      2.296296
      vbr  long      16.222222
           medium    23.111111
           short      1.888889
mpeg  amr  long      16.666667
           medium    22.629630
           short      2.074074
      cbr  long      16.222222
           medium    24.629630
           short      2.222222
      vbr  long      15.740741
           medium    23.222222
           short      2.185185
pcm   amr  long      17.037037
           medium    21.888889
           short      2.481481
      cbr  long      15.629630
           medium    22.481481
           short      1.777778
      vbr  long      15.518519
           medium    23.555556
           short      2.259259
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! yes I need to apply probabilities on multiple columns at once, is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Seems like you'd have to formulate this a conditional probabilities then? In other words, do you want 30% of vbr for mode AFTER you've picked 40% of aac for coded, for instance? Can you give a numerical example for the proportions of each variable you'd like to sample jointly?

Comment: for example I have 100 different clips and out of these 100 I want to choose the clips (lets say X) in which I get above proportions. so that means these X cliips are chosen such a way that it will give me correct proportions of codecs AND bitrate mote AND duration. Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: But aren't the different variables dependent on each other? If I randomly pick 4-3-3 of the 3 coded values, I also get certain proportions for the other variables as a result of the codec sample. These may or may not match your specs. If you want to get defined proportions at the same time for all variables then this looks more like an optimization problem than a random sample issue, or am I missing something?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and that is why preferably it should be iterative so that it will keep selecting X amount of clip and looking for this combinations until it find perfect or close enough match.

Comment: Is there any way in Pandas where I can cross join all the conditions together to get this result? It does not matter how long it takes to get the result.

Comment: You can `.merge()` using `how='outer'` but not sure that will solve the problem. First, you probably want to cross-tab the variables to understand the joint frequency distribution in the dataset. If you don't care how long it takes perhaps start with a brute-force approach where you sample one of the groups, possibly with replacement, and check for the frequencies of the remaining variables.

Comment: Can you suggest how do I do that? any pointer with example or if there is similar example available will be helpful to understand it. Thanks